# Why cant virtual dom prevent my child component rerendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent and child components, In my example, when increase button was clicked, child is gonna be rerendered.

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';

export const App = (props) => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 
const handleCount = ()=>{ 
    setCount(count+1); 
  } 
useEffect(()=>{console.log("Parent was rerendered")})
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>This is parent</h1>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>increase</button>
      <Child/>
    </div>
  );
}

const Child = props => {
useEffect(()=>{console.log('Child was rerendered')})
return (<>
<h1>This is child</h1>
</>)
}
```

I think it is pretty simply. And I also understand that, to prevent child rendering, I could us memo.

However, at some point, I studied the the concept of **virtual dom**. In it, it explained that the greatest of React is that it can prevent unchanged components to get rerendered, in order to prevent unnecessary computation.

If virual dom exist, isnt it that my child didnt change at all? Why is that my child get rerender eventually?

Edit:
I have to emphasize that my question is not about how to prevent it from re rendering. I knew the existence of memo. My question is virtual dom. React says virtual dom can compare the previous and current UI, then it will automatically prevent unchanged component from re rendering. If that's the case, why my example still got rendered? When virtual dom comes it, it doesnt make sense at all. Please dont neglect my concerns on **virtual dom** when providing answer

Comment: The fact that the child component's render function got called doesn't mean it was actually applied to the DOM. The optimization happens during read/writes to the DOM, and sometimes, [React will even bail out of rendering children](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) if the state didn't change and React caught it.

Answer (score -1):

Changing parent state triggers re-rendering the component along with its children. Your child component will be re-rendered when you press 'increase' button without regard to its internal changes in view of the code you shared.

To prevent children from re-rendering, you may use React.memo like below

```
const Button = React.memo((props: PropsWithChildren<any>) => {

    return (
        <Button type="button" color={props.color} size={props.size} onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.label}
        </Button>
    );
});
```

If you do not use that kind of approach, children will be re-rendered by default.

If you wonder opposite; if state changes in child component, that will not cause parent component re-rendering. But there are ways to make that happen.

NOTE: DOM will not update unless something changed

Further reading

[React Memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

**UPDATE**

I guess there's a misconception. When you press the 'increase` button, there will be **re-rendering**

The scenario:

When the state of a component changes, React updates the virtual DOM. React then compares the current version of the virtual DOM with the previous virtual DOM.

After comparing both and finding out which objects have changed, React updates them.

React updates DOM only if the render process produces changes. I hope it is now more clear to you.

To better understand, here's an article

[React Virtual Dom](https://adhithiravi.medium.com/react-virtual-dom-explained-in-simple-english-fc2d0b277bc5#:%7E:text=When%20the%20state%20of%20a,version%20of%20the%20virtual%20DOM.)

**EXTRA UPDATE**

Let's assume that two red nodes shown in the picture below are your components in the DOM (parent and child respectively)

[image]

When you press the 'increase' button in the parent component, it changes the inner state which leads to re-rendering of parent component along with its child component. So two red circles are re-rendered.

React, compares the old Virtual DOM and brand new Virtual DOM. Even if your parent and child component re-rendered, that will not lead to an update on the Real DOM because there's neither a visible change nor a structural change. You can think of it such as showing the current number on your parent component as a text. To visualize it, please take a look at the code below:

```
export const App = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 

  const handleCount = () => setCount(count+1);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h3>Current count: {count}</h3>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>increase</button>
      <Child/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, we have changed your parent component with an additional h3 tag in which we show the current count. In this case, if we press the 'increase' button that will lead to re-render again and this time the Real DOM will be updated because React will find out that there's a difference between old and new versions of the Virtual DOM.

So rendering and updating the real DOM are different processes.

> Back to React.memo

If you use React.memo in your child component, React will render it, memoize the result instead of re-rendering and React will not perform a Virtual DOM difference check.

Comment: sorry that, I have emphasised that my question is not about how to prevent it from re rendering. I knew the existence of memo. My question is virtual dom. React says virtual dom can compare the previous and current UI, then it will automatically prevent unchanged component from re rendering. If that's the case, why we my example still got rendered? I understand what you said completely, but when virtual dom comes it, it doesnt make sense at all.

Comment: If Re rendering comes first, what is the point of doing comparison after it? Because if re rendering everything is already occurred, that means a new page is already generated.....

Comment: Isnt it that doing comparsion is to let dom do less update? if comparsion is done only after updating the page, what is the point?

Comment: wait... I see that it seems rendering and dom update have different meaning in your context ? I thought they are the same? But how could that be different? dom update means drawing the page again.... rendering means drawing it as well?

Comment: Yes, coz your first answer doesnt address to my question at all, I dont see how doing diff only after rendering could help to do less work.... In my case above, unnecessary rendering has already been done ( child re render) ...

Comment: Comparison will be done before dom update, my bad.

Comment: State update -> comparison of Virtual Doms -> re-rendering -> update on changed parts of Real Dom.

Comment: if your flow is correct, In your second step, comparison of Virtual Doms, child component shouldnt get updated at all right? coz there is no change in child component. But, in fact, child get re render

Comment: By default, all children will be re-rendered even if there is no state change in it but that re-render doesn't necessarily changes the Real Dom

Comment: Ok, here is the core of my question comes.... If the purpose of virtual dom is to aviod unessary update... why we still see the children update even no state change in it?

Comment: Virtual DOM re-renders but the child will not be updated because there is no visible change

Comment: you just said child will be re render, but then say it will not be updated.... I was confused....could you illustrate an example in why re-render doesn't necessarily changes the Real Dom in the answer?

Comment: Virtual DOM re-renders, updates  but the child will not be updated because there is no visible change. It updates the real DOM only at the places where something has changed

Comment: We are talking about comparing Virtual Doms then updating the parts of Real Dom in which something changed

Comment: It generates a new Virtual DOM after state change and compare it with previous one and update Real DOM accordingly.

Comment: As you said Virtual DOM re-renders, it means the new virtual dom indicate that child components is updated because of the fact that it got re rendered. Then after the comparsion, it also indicate there is a change in child.... then in the real dom change, it will also change the child in real dom. Then, there is also a unnesccary updated and re render right?

Comment: Only changed parts are updated on Real DOM. Re rendering does not always produce an update on the Real DOM.

Comment: If you use React.memo, you will also prevent re-rendering of your child component, a performance gain..

Comment: Re-rendering and updating Real DOM are different processes

Comment: But how? you said virtual dom will updated when its get re rendering (parent and child) ... And in that update, virtual dom will record the re rendering in parent and child.....  which part of Real dom will change is only depends on the virtual dom.... Then in the virtual dom, it said the change is in parent and child.... Then how real dom only update the parents ?

Comment: I knew memo... But you didnt answer to the question why update in virtual dom  (parent and child) could eventually only update parent in real dom

Comment: I have updated my answer for a last time.

Comment: Thanks for adding the content, Then my next question is, if we can already update the virtual dom which represent the current status, why dont we simply update the real Dom. Why do we bother to update a virtual dom, then do a comparsion, then update a real dom. I knew you may say, after comparsion, then we may only update the neccesary part. But in latest virtual dom, we even already had a whole new dom that represent our latest dom already .......

Comment: @AeLeung the bottleneck is DOM read/writes, which is made even worse when reading and writing in quick successions (just like we did back in the day with jQuery). React solves this by (almost) never reading the DOM, keeping the state as raw data instead of in elements on the page, and writing only what's needed, when needed, hence the virtual DOM.

Comment: @AeLeung Manipulating the DOM is slow. Manipulating the virtual DOM is much faster, because nothing gets drawn onscreen. You understand now?

Comment: Ok, now comes to the essence of the question, Why is virtual dom faster than dom, even though they are both called dom.  ( and why update virtual dom is faster than real dom) I think only answering this can solve the magic of why virtual dom do the magic, instead of simply remembering virtual dom is fast, then we are all set. How does virtual dom different than dom and look like exactly....

Comment: @AeLeung the browser is slow because of the actual [repaint and reflow process](https://dev.to/gopal1996/understanding-reflow-and-repaint-in-the-browser-1jbg) that the virtual DOM doesn't do.

Comment: @EmileBergeron But isnt it that when the re render function occur, a new virtual dom would be created, and it means repaint has been occured?

Comment: @AeLeung part of the virtual DOM is replaced with the result of the component return value, which is inexpensive, then React figures out if there is anything that should be applied to the real DOM and does it in a single write. Repaint only occurs if React did write to the browser's DOM,  but either way, React might still call relevant components render function to know if the virtual DOM actually changed.